# SlugField в админке

Tags: django, slug

Пытаюсь настроить автоматическое добавление поля `slug` основанном на заголовке статьи с переводом в латинские символы в админке при создании статьи. Проблема в том, что при первом сохранении латинская транслитерация работает, но если зайти для правки статьи, то `slug` изменяется идентично `title` и отображается на  русском языке.

Подскажите, что не так в коде?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Tags(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = RichTextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True, default='' )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('index')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title, allow_unicode=True)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Tags, Post


class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}

admin.site.register(Post,PostAdmin)
admin.site.register(Tags)
# Register your models here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал в своём проекте [*uuslug*](https://github.com/un33k/django-uuslug): (`from uuslug import uuslug`)

```
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = uuslug(self.title, instance=self)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Работает как надо.
С другими тоже были какие то проблемы, разбираться не стал, так как не было времени на такие мелочи.

Comment: Я просто убрал def save и все заработало